# Deleting a Changelist in perforce

Tags: perforce

I am using P4V client and would like to know if there is a way to delete your submitted changelist without affecting your current working directory in any way. I made a mistake in the commit and left something out and i would like it gone from the server. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rollback the file, submit, then make the correct changelist.  This would technically still leave the old changelist in place, but would create a history of you fixing the mistake.

I believe Perforce is philosophically against deleting changelists, though there could be a method I'm unaware of.

Comment: Though this is definitely a bad way in almost all cases there's the possibility to call "p4 obliterate" to completely remove revisions/files from the server including their meta data (like changelists/history etc.). This requires the corresponding permissions.